# How to use condition in xml fieldset

Tags: php, html, xml, joomla

I have two eddition in my realise joomla web app. "Common" and "Special" edition.

I want to limit "Common" edition with exclude "icons" dir from "images".

```xml
<fileset dir="./images">
    <include name="**/**" />
    <exclude name="icons/**" />
</fileset>
```

expected:

```xml
<fileset dir="./images">
    <include name="**/**" />

    IN Common Eddition : <exclude name="icons/**" />

</fileset>
```

I tried the following code but it was not correct (Apparently, `if` segment cannot be used within `fileset`)

```xml
<fileset dir="./images">
    <include name="**/**" />

    <if>
        <equals arg1="${edition}" arg2="Common"/>
        <then>
            <exclude name="icons/**" />
        </then>
    </if>
</fileset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `condition`  for this

```xml
<condition property="pass">
    <equals arg1="${edition}" arg2="common" />
</condition>
<fileset dir="./images">
    <include name="**/**" />
    <exclude name="icons/**" if="pass" />
</fileset>
```